# Richfaces togglePanel facets do not allow setting the style for each facet?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have a rich:togglePanel with two facets. I want the contents of the togglepanel, whatever facet is active at that case, to have **width=100% and height="100%"**. For this I have created the  **expandAll**.

The problem is that the facet "renders" a div named **togglePanel_open**, whose content (the panelGrid) **has** class expandAll, but **itself** (the togglePanel_open) does not. As such, its contents "stretch" to their parent, which unfortunately does not "stretch" to its own parent, which is what I would like to achieve.

Has anyone any idea how to overcome this?

Cheers!

```
<rich:togglePanel id="treeTogglePanel"
            styleClass="expandAll" value="open" switchType="client"
            stateOrder="open,closed">

            <f:facet name="open">
                <h:panelGrid styleClass="expandAll"
                    ...
                </h:panelGrid>
                ...
            </f:facet>


            <f:facet name="closed">
                <h:panelGrid styleClass="expandAll"
                    ...
                </h:panelGrid>
                ...
            </f:facet>
```

**UPDATE:**  What I currently do to work around the problem (not solve it) is that I explicitly define in the CSS the style of the element #togglePanel_open. But this is a very nasty hack (or as we say in Greece, a very "Tarzan-like" thing to do:-)  ), because if in the next Richfaces version they name the generated divs differently, this will stop to work.

Comment: please provide the entire code of the page (maybe in an external source), so that I can observe what exactly is happening.